# Bucle while infinito - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este ejercicio es una simulacion de un sistema de llegada de barcos jugando con numeros aleatorios. Inicialmente se corre un número aleatorio para saber cuantos barcos llegan en el dia. inmediatamente se genera otro para ver cuantos barcos de los que llegaron pueden descargar mercancia. Los que no pudieron descargar ese dia, lo podran hacer al siguiente, y se acumulará a los barcos del siguiente dia.
un ejemplo de lo que seria el programa:

```
#   ALEAT   BARCOS  ACUM    ALEAT2  DESCARGADOS RESTANTE
1   0.678     3       0     0.823       2          1
2   0.806     4       1     0.401       3          2
3   0.967     5       2     0.785       5          2
4   0.116     1       2     0.463       2          1
5   0.760     4       1     0.850       4          1
6   0.103     0       1     0.019       0          1
7   0.849     4       1     0.524       2          3
8   0.566     3       3     0.215       3          3
9   0.567     4       3     0.936       4          3
10  0.122     5       3     0.398       4          4
11  0.455     1       4     0.533       1          4
12  0.165     1       4     0.883       1          4
13  0.031     2       4     0.983       2          4
14  0.571     5       4     0.357       3          6
15  0.513     1       6     0.835       1          6
```

En el codigo que tengo, genero un # aleatorio para saber cuantos barcos entran a descargar, la variable descargados no debe ser mayor al número de barcos que llegan. mi idea fue hacer un `while` para generar otro # aleatorio hasta que se generara una cantidad menor a barcos que llegan.

Cuando corro el programa, se congela intentando generar un numero aleatorio que sea menor que la variable `barcos`, pero hay veces que si se ejecuta con normalidad.

```
from random import random

i=1
Acum = 0
count = 0
barcos = 0
sumaacum = 0

print("#\tALEAT\tBARCOS\tACUM\tSumaAcum\tALEAT\tBdESCAR\tREST")
while i <= 15:
    aleat=random()
    if aleat < 0.13:
        barcos = 0
    elif aleat < 0.3:
        barcos = 1
    elif aleat < 0.45:
        barcos = 2
    elif aleat < 0.7:
        barcos = 3
    elif aleat < 0.9:
        barco = 4
    else:
        barcos = 5

    while True:
        aleat2 = random()
        if aleat2 < 0.05:
            descargados = 1
        elif aleat2 < 0.2:
            descargados = 2
        elif aleat2 < 0.7:
            descargados = 3
        elif aleat2 < 0.9:
            descargados = 4
        else:
            descargados = 5
        if descargados > barcos:
            aleat2 = random()  
        else:
            break

    sumaacum = barcos + Acum
    restan = sumaacum - descargados
    count += restan
    print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(i,str(aleat)[0:5],barcos,Acum,sumaacum,str(aleat2)[0:5],descargados,restan))

    Acum = restan
    i+=1
print("el total de barcos con retardo son: {}".format(count))
```

la salida del programa es:

```
#       ALEAT   BARCOS  ACUM    SumaAcum        ALEAT   BdESCAR REST
1       0.426   2       0       2       0.199   2       0
2       0.866   2       0       2       0.000   1       1
3       0.536   3       1       4       0.066   2       2
4       0.679   3       2       5       0.154   2       3
5       0.857   3       3       6       0.673   3       3
6       0.983   5       3       8       0.646   3       5
7       0.772   5       5       10      0.028   1       9
8       0.520   3       9       12      0.516   3       9
9       0.748   3       9       12      0.109   2       10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cisco\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 30, in <module>
    descargados = 2
KeyboardInterrupt
```

En esta ocacion, el programa se queda tratando de generar un # aleatorio talque barcos `descargados` sea menor que `barcos` que llegan. Tuve que deterner el programa presionando Ctrl + c para ejecutar el programa denuevo.

```
#       ALEAT   BARCOS  ACUM    SumaAcum        ALEAT   BdESCAR REST
1       0.335   2       0       2       0.052   2       0
2       0.490   3       0       3       0.605   3       0
3       0.830   3       0       3       0.643   3       0
4       0.492   3       0       3       0.657   3       0
5       0.360   2       0       2       0.169   2       0
6       0.503   3       0       3       0.560   3       0
7       0.752   3       0       3       0.327   3       0
8       0.508   3       0       3       0.518   3       0
9       0.500   3       0       3       0.407   3       0
10      0.971   5       0       5       0.003   1       4
11      0.503   3       4       7       0.522   3       4
12      0.581   3       4       7       0.170   2       5
13      0.549   3       5       8       0.103   2       6
14      0.183   1       6       7       0.035   1       6
15      0.767   1       6       7       0.006   1       6
el total de barcos con retardo son: 31
```

En esta corrida, el programa se ejecuto sin problemas.

¿De qué otra forma puedo hacer la validacion para que no forme bucles infinitos y evitar estos incvonvenientes?
Gracias

Comment: Lo primero, por qué usas el ramdom así, si quieres que pueda haber 5 barcos puedes hacer que el ramdom sea un número entre entre 0 y 5. `from random import randint print(randint(0, 5))` esto te dará un número entre 0 y 5. De esta forma el primer conjunto de if/else te lo podrías quitar Y saber directamente los barcos que van a ser si ver si el ramdom es mayor que 0.65 por ejemplo.

Comment: El bucle infinito viene cuando el primer aleatorio sale barcos 0 (entra al primer if), entonces descargados que no puede ser 0 (no lo contemplas) siempre va a ser mayor que 0. Entonces se produce el bucle infinito.

Comment: @RodriKing, imagino que Juan utiliza esta forma para poder variar las probabilidades de cada uno de los valores, con `randint()`  y/o `random()` se usa una distribución uniforme, dónde cada valor tiene la misma probabilidad.

Comment: ¿Que versión de Python estás usando?

Comment: utilizo python 3.7.0, Como tu lo dices, dependiendo del numero aleatorio que sale, se le asigna una probabilidad y numero de barcos respectivos.

Comment: @JUANRAMIREZ Para el bucle infinito, arriba te digo porque está pasando cambiando eso ya estaría solucionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comento arriba, el bucle infinito se da cuando la variable `barcos` es `0`. Entonces la comparación que haces en `if descargados > barcos:` siempre se va a cumplir.

Te pongo una solución a ver si te sirve un poco más simple de lo que tu haces.

```
from random import randint

i = 1
acum = 0
count = 0
barcos = 0
sumaacum = 0

print("#\tALEAT\tBARCOS\tACUM\tSumaAcum\tALEAT\tBdESCAR\tREST")
while i <= 15:
    barcos = randint(0, 5)

    descargados = randint(0, barcos)

    sumaacum = barcos + acum
    restan = sumaacum - descargados
    count += restan
    print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(i, str(barcos)[0:5], barcos, acum, sumaacum, str(descargados)[0:5],
                                                  descargados, restan))

    acum = restan
    i += 1
print("el total de barcos con retardo son: {}".format(count))
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, si es una forma mas simplificada de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema fundamental es que tienes un ciclo que se hará infinito en caso que `barcos == 0`, no estás controlando dicha situación. Creo además que el problema se puede plantear de una forma más sencilla. La idea sería

- Cada día llegan `x` barcos y ese día en particular tienes una capacidad para descargar `y` barcos
- Si descargas más de los que llegan iras reduciendo  los eventuales pendientes pero solo hasta llegar a 0, obviamente no puedes tener pendientes negativos

Lo otro que agrega complejidad es como obtener los dos valores aleatorios con una distribución no uniforme. Por suerte a partir de la versión 3.6, Python incorpora en [`choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices) la posibilidad de agregar un peso para cada elemento de una lista de valores a aleatorizar, y mejor aún, se pueden indicar los pesos acumulados `cum_weights` que son los valores has definido.

Veamos:

```
from random import choices

barcos_probs = [.13, .3, .45, .7, .9, 1]
descargas_probs = [.05, .2, .7, .9,  1]

pendientes = 0
print("#\tBARCOS\tDESC\tPEND")

for i in range(1,16):

  barcos_hoy = choices([0,1,2,3,4,5], cum_weights = barcos_probs)[0]
  descarga_hoy = choices([1,2,3,4,5], cum_weights = descargas_probs)[0]

  descargados = descarga_hoy if descarga_hoy < (pendientes + barcos_hoy) else (pendientes + barcos_hoy)
  pendientes = (pendientes + barcos_hoy) - descargados

  print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(i, barcos_hoy, descarga_hoy, pendientes))
```

Explicación:

- Simulamos unos 15 días `for i in range(1,16)`
- Cada día llegan distintas cantidades de barcos y tenemos distintas capacidades de descargas
- Pueden llegar de 0 a 5 barcos y podemos descargar de 1 a 5 de estos
- Llevamos un acumulado de barcos pendientes
- ¿Cuantos podremos descargar en el día? la capacidad que tengamos hasta la cantidad de pendientes. No podemos descargar más de los que tenemos pendientes.

Obviamente este es un planteamiento rápido y sencillo, deberías validarlo.